# How can i restrict multiple timer function calling a function at same time? Swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift3, nstimer, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have 5 timers running with a different time interval.All these timers calling the same function.
At a certain time, one or more timer function trying to access the same method, this will crash my app.

How I can implement NSOperation queue for this particular scenario.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: have you tried with Dispatch Queue ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any queue. This is the my first requirement.

Comment: It will help us to understand if you share your code.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a dispatch queue with label.

```
 let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "update")  //  later on your "other threads"

queue.sync {                                                
//perform any task you want
}
```

In your each timer use the above code. In this way all will be able to execute this "update" thread only when it will be free